# Crystal Report Running Total

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, cumulative-sum

I am creating a report (screenshot is attached below) in which I have to show running total of column `Balance`. This `balance` column value is generated by adding or subtracting `dr` and `cr` column value. For more explanation, if `dr` is `0` then `cr` value will be subtracted from `balance` value and if `cr` is `0` then `dr` value will be added to `balance` value, and the `balance` column first value will come from `particulars (=opening)` column's `dr` or `cr` value then the calculation will start and running total of `balance` will be made.

I have attempted some Crystal Report formulas to accomplish this but failed to get the required values. I have also attached snapshot of my attempted formulas.

First page of report
[image: this image is first page of report]

This image is the formula I used in this report for running total. But this approach is not calculating the correct sum and this formula is not working on next page of report as it starts from the beginning on next page

[image: this image is the formulas in this report]

If anyone knows any other useful and easy way to calculate running total which is suitable in my current situation then please guide me.

Comment: Which header are you talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish it this way. Create two formula fields in report design, namely `ff_Reset_Bal`, `ff_Cur_Bal` and set their values in formula editor as under:

1. ff_Reset_Bal

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   numbervar RunTotl;
   RunTotl:=0;
   ```
2. ff_Cur_Bal

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   numbervar RunTotl;
   RunTotl:=RunTotl + {WLBills.dr} - {WLBills.cr};
   ```

Now place these formula fields in your report as under:

1. `ff_Reset_Bal` in the *Report Header* Section (**its Report Header NOT Page Header**)
2. `ff_Cur_Bal` in the *Details* Section (this is your **Balance column** in report)

Now hide `ff_Reset_Bal` by `Right Click` on it in *Report Header*, point to `Format Field` and then in the `Common` tab select `Suppress`

Comment: Thank you so much sir, its working 100%. but there is another issue. i want to show total of this ff_cur_bal formula in report footer. when i right click on it in details tab of report for inserting summary there is no option for summary and when i write a custom sum function for summarizing it. it show error that this field cannot be summarized. please help. and thanks again you made my day.

Comment: @ haramna : sir please guide me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Sum of `ff_Cur_Bal` seems a bit odd to me, most likely your requirement is to display last/closing balance in the report footer, if it is so then just place `ff_Cur_Bal` in the *Report Footer* Section also

Comment: hmm yes you are right i have to show the last closing balance in the report. but when place ff_cur_bal in the report footer along with the summary or "dr" and "cr" column it shows different result. for example last "balance" is 39,404 and last "dr" amount is 1800, when i place that formula in footer it shows 41,204 amount after adding last "dr" amount in it which is 1800. i tried to save ff_cur_bal last value in another formula and placed that in footer but same results i got. please help in getting out of this situation. Thank you sir for you time and support

Comment: In that case you can create more formula 1) `sumDr` as `Sum({WLBills.dr})` 2) `sumCr` as `Sum({WLBills.cr})` and 3) `finalBal` as `{@sumDr}-{@sumCr}`. Then place `finalBal` in the footer

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much. it worked. now i am getting accurate results. Thanks for your support and precious time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create running total directly in CR - in Field Explorer add Running Total field. What to sum - for this I would create a formula, containing just `{WLBills.dr} - {WLBills.cr}`. If you have some grouping, remember to evaluate running total only at correct group change.

Comment: Thank you for your support.